# Find Port Number and Domain Name to connect to Hive Table

Tags: bash, unix, hadoop, hive

I am new to Hive, MapReduce and Hadoop.
I am using Putty to connect to hive table and access records in the tables. So what I did is- I opened Putty and in the host name I typed- `vip.host.com` and then I click `Open`. And then I entered my username and password and then few commands to get to Hive sql. Below is the list what I did

```
$ bash
bash-3.00$ hive
Hive history file=/tmp/unl/hive_job_log_unl_201207010451_1212680168.txt
hive> set mapred.job.queue.name=mdhi-technology;
hive> select * from table LIMIT 1;
```

So my question is-

I was trying to connect to `Hive Tables` using `Squirrel SQL Client`, so in that my Connection URL is- `jdbc:hive://vip.host.com:10000/default`. So whenever I try to connect with these attributes, I always get `Hive: Could not establish connection to vip.host.com:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`.

It might be possible I am using `wrong port number or domain name here`. Is there any way from the command prompt I can find out these two things, like what Domain Name and Port Number(where Hive server is running) should I use to connect to Hive table from Squirrel SQL Client.

**As I know host and port are determined by where the hive server is running**

Answer (score 4):

Posting this after quite some time. I did not get lsof command. So used this workaround.

If you have hive access:

```
hive> set hive.metastore.uris;

hive.metastore.uris=thrift://sandbox.hortonworks.com:9083
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to login to hiveCLI, you just have to execute below property.

```
hive> set hive.server2.thrift.port;
```

It should give you the port number where hiveserver2 is running. It looks something like below.

```
hive.server2.thrift.port=10014
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the host and can logon: try

```
/usr/sbin/lsof -i
```

Comment: I tried, it says command not found. `$ bash
bash-3.00$ lsof -i
bash: lsof: command not found
`

Comment: generally it's in /sbin or /usr/sbin, not in the path by default

Comment: I tried in `sbin` folder and `/usr/sbin` folder too. Still says `command not found`